# Spherical basis tensors

Tags: tensors, quantum-mechanics, change-of-basis

I was studying spherical basis as part of a physics course, and I stumbled the spherical representation of tensors. In Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_basis) I found that any operator in the spherical basis satisfies the following commutation relationships:

$$[J_z,T_q]=\hbar q V_q$$

$$[J_{\pm},T_q]=\hbar \sqrt{(1\mp q)(2\pm q)}V_{q\pm 1}$$

However, I would like to know if it's possible to deduce this commutators or if these are just mere definitions, as all the textbooks and articles I've read just state these commutators and then work on other definitions built from these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not definitions. If you have not come across raising and lowering operators, I would recommend to start on something simple.
First you have 
\begin{equation}
[J_x,J_y]= i\hbar J_z
\end{equation}
and cyclic permutations. 
You also have 
\begin{equation}
[{\bf J}^2,{\bf J}]=0
\end{equation}
Then you define 
\begin{equation}
J_{\pm}=J_x\pm iJ_y
\end{equation}
and show a bunch of commutation relations, for instance
\begin{equation}
[\bf{J}^2,J_\pm]=0, 
\end{equation}
and so on and express $\bf{J}^2$ in terms of $J_z$ and $J_\pm$. It is then possible to derive the common spectrum of ${\bf J}^2$ and $J_z$ (the eigenvalues of ${\bf J^2}$ can be written as $\hbar^2 j(j+1)$ and those of $J_z$ as $m\hbar$, with j either integer or half-integer and $m$ integer). All of this  is material you will use over and over again in your studies. It is worth spending time on. I think you would be better off reading a standard textbook like Cohen Tannoudji, Quantum mechanics I, chapter VI, Angular momentum in quantum mechanics, see [here](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Quantum+Mechanics%2C+Volume+1-p-9780471164333)

Finally, to get back to your question the spherical harmonics that you encountered are just a 3D representation of the angular momentum algebra above with integer values for $j$. The concept is much more general though and is also the basis for treating spin 1/2 particles.

Comment: Thank you. I've already studied and proved the commutators or angular momentum your mentioned during college, and the material I'm showing is actually part of my first graduate course in QM (which was touched briefly due to time-constraints). I indeed read about their relation to spherical harmonics, and books like the Sakurai and Weinberg state that all spherical operators can be defined as those who satisfy the commutators in the OP. However, based on the definitions I managed to proof the commutators above, so don't worry I just found the answer :)

Comment: Ok, brilliant.  Sakurai wrote great books.